# Azure dev ops upgrade deleted pipeline history

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines

We've just upgraded from TFS to azure dev ops and it seems that a lot of our builds have lost all their run history which has broken our build versioning using $(rev:.r). The retention policy on the project is the default 30 days 3 runs and it seems to (mostly) be pipelines that haven't been run for a long time that are impacted. But there is also at least one pipeline that has a run from April so it's not exclusively that they're old. I can't find anything online but is there any precedent for upgrading to azure dev ops removing all runs from a pipeline?

Comment: I remember a known issue when going to Azure DevOps 2020 RTW. From what verion to what version did you upgrade.

Comment: We went from TFS 2017 to Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.  From looking at the SQL table [Build].[tbl_Build] for the default collection it looks like builds are missing after the 30 day retention period (in our case from before 9th of august) apart from 5 builds that have been retained for some reason i cant figure out as they arent marked to be kept.

Comment: I've also commented below on an answer with slightly more info, if you have any more advice it would be much appreciated. Thanks